# &[T] changed to Vec<&T>

Tags: rust

I wrote a function that accepts a slice of single digit numbers and returns a number.

```
pub fn from_digits<T>(digits: &[T]) -> T
where
    T: Num + FromPrimitive + Add + Mul + Copy,
{
    let mut ret: T = T::zero();
    let ten: T = T::from_i8(10).unwrap();
    for d in digits {
        ret = ret * ten + **d;
    }
    ret
}
```

For example, `from_digits(&vec![1,2,3,4,5])` returns `12345`. This seems to work fine.

Now, I want to use this function in another code:

```
let ret: Vec<Vec<i64>> = digits // &[i64]
  .iter()                       // Iter<i64>
  .rev()                        // impl Iterator<Item = i64>
  .permutations(len)            // Permutations<Rev<Iter<i64>>>
  .map(|ds| from_digits(&ds))   // <-- ds: Vec<&i64>
  .collect();
```

The problem is that after `permutations()`, the type in the lambda in `map` is `Vec<&i64>`, not `Vec<i64>`. This caused the compile error, as the expected parameter type is `&[T]`, not `&[&T]`.

I don't understand why the type of `ds` became `Vec<&i64>`. I tried to change the `from_digits` like this:

```
pub fn from_digits<T>(digits: &[&T]) -> T
...
```

But I am not sure if this is the correct way to fix the issue. Also, this caused another problem that I cannot pass simple data like `vec![1,2,3]` to the function.

Can you let me know the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Second line where `.iter()` is called says "Iter<i64>" whereas it's actually "Iter<&i64>". You can fix that by doing "iter().copied()"

Comment: Shouldn't `ret` have type `Vec<i64>`?

Comment: @stepan It's `Iter<i64>` however it implements `Iterator<Item = &T>` or `Iterator<Item = &i64>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh, yes, it should be `Vector<i64>`. I packed the digits to a number with `from_digits()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that slice's `iter()` function returns an iterator over `&T`, so `&i64`.

The fix is to use the [`Iterator::copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) or [`Iterator::cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) adapters that converts and iterator over `&T` to an iterator over `T` when `T: Copy` or `T: Clone`, respectively:

```rust
digits.iter().copied().rev() // ...
```